# XSL Wrapping of siblings tags into a section tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml

I need to wrap all the elements after the `<p class="- topic/p " outputclass="Endofclause">` if the first sibling starts with Alternate into a section tag. I used an xsl to do the wrapping, but after the wrapping it copied the same contents over again.

How to modify the xsl so that after the wrapping it dont copy the contents again?
Thanks

This is the input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<dita>
    <concept>
        <title>
            <ph>Page 5</ph> TEST XML</title>
        <conbody>
            <p>As prescribed in <ph>
                    <xref href="test2.dita#1234">2 TEST</xref>(a)</ph>, insert the following
                clause:</p>
            <p class="- topic/p " id="d3235e15" outputclass="Ctr_SmCaps">Shipment and Payment</p>
            
            <p class="- topic/p " outputclass="Endofclause">(End of clause)</p>
            
                <p class="- topic/p " id="d3238e514">
                    <i class="+ topic/ph hi-d/i ">Alternate I</i> </p>
                
                <p class="- topic/p ">
                    A2</p>
            <p class="- topic/p ">
                A3</p>
 
        </conbody>
    </concept>
</dita>
```

This is the xsl i used

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <!-- Identity transform template -->
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <!-- Match the p element with attribute outputclass="Endofclause" -->
    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Endofclause']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        
        <!-- Check if the first sibling has text that starts with "Alternate" -->
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Alternate')]]">
            <section>
                <!-- Wrap all following siblings in a <section> element -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*"/>
            </section>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dita>
    <concept>
        <title>
            <ph>Page 5</ph> TEST XML</title>
        <conbody>
            <p>As prescribed in <ph>
                    <xref href="test2.dita#1234">2 TEST</xref>(a)</ph>, insert the following
                clause:</p>
            <p class="- topic/p " id="d3235e15" outputclass="Ctr_SmCaps">Shipment and Payment</p>
            
            <p class="- topic/p " outputclass="Endofclause">(End of clause)</p><section><p class="- topic/p " id="d3238e514">
                    <i class="+ topic/ph hi-d/i ">Alternate I</i> </p><p class="- topic/p ">
                    A2</p><p class="- topic/p ">
                A3</p></section>
            
                <p class="- topic/p " id="d3238e514">
                    <i class="+ topic/ph hi-d/i ">Alternate I</i> </p>
                
                <p class="- topic/p ">
                    A2</p>
            <p class="- topic/p ">
                A3</p>
 
        </conbody>
    </concept>
</dita>
```

Comment: You have a previous question where the solution uses `for-each-group group-starting-with`. That should work for the above case as well, although that single example doesn't really suffice what kind of content you want to process and how you want to transform it  (e.g. can there be more than one such element for which you want to wrap following siblings?).

Comment: You might find this post useful for doing sibling recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861479/xslt-muenchian-grouping-create-key-inside-group - It isn't an easy thing to grasp, and xsl:for-each-group is much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of trying to use `for-each-group group-starting-with` your conditions could be morphed into e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[p[@outputclass='Endofclause'][following-sibling::*[1][self::p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Alternate')]]]]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Alternate')][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p[@outputclass='Endofclause']]]">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Alternate')][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p[@outputclass='Endofclause']]]">
              <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </section>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:template match="*[p[@outputclass='Endofclause'][following-sibling::*[1][self::p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Alternate')]]]]">` might be too complex, I can't tell whether `<xsl:template match="*[p]">` or `<xsl:template match="conbody">` would suffice, it all depends on the possible input variations and where you want to apply the grouping.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked well. This is perfect 
<xsl:template match="*[p[@outputclass='Endofclause'][following-sibling::*[1][self::p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Alternate')]]]]">